# CommanderOne: Clear the servers history

Tags: macos

I am using CommanderOne to connect to smb shares. To connect to a share I press `command`+`K`. The presented history is pretty cluttered with old shares and I want to clear the history of the list. Where is the history stored?

Comment: This is less about macOS and more about CommanderOne. Have you asked this of their support or on their discussion board?

Comment: I sent a message to their support. When I get an answer I will post it here. Thought that some Mac pros would have a hint were these kind of data is usually stored though.

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer from the CommanderOne support:

> To clear the history of the list, use the following command in Terminal (Ctrl+O):
> `defaults delete com.eltima.cmd1 TCXWindow.connect2addresses`
>
> Please, note that settings ID (`com.eltima.cmd1`) varies based on Commander One version, that you have installed:
> Website: `com.eltima.cmd1`
> AppStore free: `com.eltima.cmd1.mas`
> AppStore PRO: `com.eltima.cmd1.pro.mas`
> SetApp: `com.eltima.cmd1-setapp`